# Plugin is not generating title tags on any pages or posts

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am using the Wordpress SEO plug in and for some reason the plug in is not longer adding title tags to any posts or pages. I just updated my theme, and something has changed between this version and the last one regarding the way it works with the Wordpress SEO plugin. I checked the header.php and as far as I can tell it has the correct code:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

If I deactivate the plugin the titles come back. Does anyone have any ideas of what could be happening? I'll be happy to supply any code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an issue with a plug in (Wordpress SEO) and the theme. I had to click the check box for "enable title rewrite" within the plug in settings in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting rid of the single quotes: `<?php wp_title(); ?>`